# Match word which is not enclosed in quotes in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

(Sorry for my broken English)
I'm trying to match an `or` in a string and if it is not enclosed in single quotes and replace it with a minus sign (`-`).
For example:

```
local input1 = "'condition1' or 'condition2'" 
input1:gsub(pattern, "-")  --> Should return "'condition1' - 'condition2'"

local input2 = "'condition1 or condition2'"  -- Note the position of the '
input2:gsub(pattern, "-")  --> Should return "'condition1 or condition2'"
```

Where `pattern` is the Lua pattern I am asking for.

Im sure that I have to use `%b''` in order to detect if the `or` is quoted, so I tried this as my pattern: `[^%b'']or`
But that doesn't work for me.

Please note that I can use only pure Lua libraries (so no `LPeg`) as the code will be runned in different Lua runtimes (all 5.2) not supporting C libraries.

And please note that this question is **not a duplicate** - there is no question asking how to do this **in Lua** with its own patterns.

Comment: Use `pattern = "(%b'')%s+or%s+(%b'')"` and for replacement use `'%1 - %2'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `input:gsub("('.-'.-)or","%1-")`.

This assumes that `or` always appears after a quoted string. It captures everything from the quoted string until just before `or` and replaces this with the captured text followed by `-`, as required.